# Filtering text out to new tab with custom command

Tags: buffers, user-commands

I would like to add to my vimrc a custom command (`:customFilter {pattern}`) for filtering text and placing result in a new tab.

I tried using `:global` or `:vimgrep /{pattern}/ %` but the problem is that I would like to redirect this result of `global` or content of `Quickfix list` (without name of file) to a new tab.

Please help.

#### Example

my file:

```
class TemperatureNode {
    + uint8_t getTemperatureValue()
    + void setTemperatureValue(uint8_t newVal)
    + uint8_t getHumidityValue()
    + void setHumidityValue(uint8_t newVal)
}
```

and then I call `:customFilter void` and get:

```
+ void setTemperatureValue(uint8_t newVal)
+ void setHumidityValue(uint8_t newVal)
```

Having this with line numbers from the filtered file would be even better.

Comment: What do you want to do with that new buffer?

Comment: This would be mainly for searching through the logs, so having few buffer/tab with results of filtering would allow me to debug more efficiently (huge app, syslog debugging). But if you're asking more literally- I want to save this buffer/tab to a file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a new empty buffer in a new tab and then populate it with the result of a grep search on the previous file:

```
:tabnew|0r!grep -n pattern #
```

In a mapping:

```
nnoremap <key> :tabnew\|0r!grep -n  #<Left><Left>
```

Which works like this:

[image]

--- edit ---

Here is an alternative command that works with the current buffer instead of the current file:

```
:%y z|tabnew|0put=@z|%!grep -n pattern
```

Explanation:

```
:%y z                 " yank the whole buffer in register z
:tabnew               " edit a new buffer in a new tab
:0put=@z              " put the yanked text in that new buffer
:%!grep -n pattern    " do your filtering
```

As a command:

```
:command! -nargs=1 -range=% Filter <line1>,<line2>y z|tabnew|0put=@z|%!grep -n '<q-args>'
```

Usage:

```
:Filter pattern        " works on the whole buffer by default
:5,20Filter pattern    " works on the supplied range
```

Comment: This is great but has a flaw- it only works with existing files and doesn't work with new buffer/tab. Do you have any idea how to make this work for unsaved files? And one more question what does #<Left><Left> and the # itself do?

EDIT: I get this <Left><Left> - it's just moving cursor for it to be in the right place to insert "pattern"

Comment: `#` represents "the alternate file" (usually it's the previous buffer). It is expanded by Vim before sending the command to the shell.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I tested it in gVim but I get "shell returned 1" and an empty buffer, but similar `:command! -nargs=1 Filter %y z|tabnew|0put=@z|%!grep -n <args>` works perfect (a little bit slow though). That's what I needed! Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

First clear an register: `qaq`
second, append all matching lines using the `:g` command:

```
:g/pattern/y A
```

Third, put all matches on a new page

```
:tabnew +$put\ A
```

If you want to be able to make changes on those filtered mached, have a look at my [NrrwRgn Plugin](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn). The advantage is, once you save the narrowed buffer, the changes will be taken back into the original buffer.

Comment: ok. this works. but I don't get what `qaq` does? it simply starts recording macro and then leave it. what's the purpose here?

Comment: As I said, clear a register